# Differential Eqn by separation of variables.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential equation:$$\frac{dx}{dt} = k(a-x)(b-x), 0 < a < b$$.

This is easy enough to solve using a partial fraction decomposition and using logs:
I get to $$\left[-\frac{1}{b-a} \ln|a-x| + \frac{1}{a-b}\ln |b-x|\right]_0^x =kt,$$ which can be expressed as $$\frac{1}{a-b} \ln\left(|(a-x)(b-x)|\right) = kt$$
Manipulating this further gives $$|(a-x)(b-x)| = e^{(a-b)kt}$$ How would I isolate $x$ now to get an explicit function $x = x(t)?$

Comment: Your partial fraction decomposition is not correct. Check it again.

Comment: You also didn't include your constant of integration, which is important toward the end.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong What is wrong with it? I checked it again. I used the fact that $(a-b) = -(b-a)$ and it works?

Comment: @JohnD I have done a definite integral.  My notation is a bit sloppy but I have the integral from $0$ to $x$ $d\hat{x}$ say and the integral from $0$ to $t$ $d\hat{t}$.  I can use this because I have an initial condition (which I forgot to put in the question - sorry)

Comment: You have a minus sign error. When corrected, it will leave you with a linear equation for $x$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Where is this minus error? EDIT: I see it now.

Comment: @AndréNicolas What I have now is $x = \frac{be^{kt(a-b)} - a}{e^{kt(a-b)} - 1}$

Comment: @CAF: This is a solution. By the way, I would use the more awkward e^{-kt(b-a)}$. And switch signs of both top and bottom. But that's just aesthetics. The serious problem is that it is **one** solution. For the general solution needed constant of integration, to be evaluated if you were given an initial condition. Even if you were not, might be good to express answer in terms of $x_0=x(0)$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I thought by setting up a definite integral I had taken care of those intial conditions and so there is no longer any need for a constant. The intial condition was simply $x(0) = 0$ and so I set up like: $$\int_0^x ..d\hat{x} = \int_0^t...d\hat{t}$$

Comment: @CAF: (i) Were you given an "initial" condition (the value of $x$ at *some* time)?  (ii) If not, when you integrate it should be (sort of) $kt+C$ on the right, then when you take off log and absolute value you get a ratio of linear things in $x$ being $De^{-kt(b-a)}$. Then finish as before. If you were given initial condition, use that to evaluate $D$.

Comment: @CAF: I started replying while you were editing comment. You will notice that your answer does not satisfy the initial condition that you had not revealed. The idea of using definite integrals is OK, then the right side is correct. The left is not, when you plug in $0$ into your log the answer is not $0$!

Comment: I see what I have done wrong..silly error. Thanks for making me aware.  I'll come back later... I have another question regarding this problem about limits.

Comment: So I tried again and get: $$x(t) = [abe^{(a-b)kt} -1]/[ae^{(a-b)kt} -b]$$.  When I take the limit as $b \rightarrow a$, I get just b, right? Now, I have to solve this explicitly in the case when $b=a$ and compare. In the end, I get for the case $b=a$, $x(t) = \frac{a^2kt}{akt+1}$.  It would seem sensible to expect the solns to match, but they don't.